# Custom Icons From More Than 1 PHP File

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, custom-controls

I wonder whether someone could help me please.

I've put together [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/mylocationstest.html) page which gives the user functionality of clicking on a map marker, selecting a radial distance from a drop down menu, allowing them to search for POI's upon clicking 'Search locations'

The page gets it's data from two php files, both with marker categories in their own right which are represented by custom icons.

When I add custom markers to my script I use this:

```
  var customIcons = { 
            "Finds made": { 
            icon: 'location-marker2.png', 
            shadow: 'location-marker2-shadow.png' 
            }, 
            "No finds made": { 
            icon: 'location-marker1.png', 
            shadow: 'location-marker1-shadow.png' 
            },
```

Then I add these lines as part of the marker creation:

```
var icon = customIcons[totalfindstext] || {};   
icon: icon.icon, 
shadow: icon.shadow,
```

This code is working fine for my first script called 'loadmylocations', but I can't get the custom markers to work for the second, 'searchscheduledsites'.

I've added the relevant lines of code to the marker creation, which in this case is

```
function createMarker2
```

But no matter where I add the variable for the marker categories i.e.

```
var customIcons = { 
                "Battlefield": { 
                icon: 'battle-marker.png', 
                shadow: 'battle-marker-shadow.png' 
                }, 
                "Monument": { 
                icon: 'monument-marker.png', 
                shadow: 'monument-marker-shadow.png'
```

I can't get them to work. I've tried cutting and pasting them all over my script and I've even called them var customicons2, just so it couldn't be mistaken for the first set, but without any luck.

I just wondered whether someone could take a look at this plase and let me know where I've gone wrong.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Missing a quote?
icon: `'`battle-marker.png',

Comment: Hi many thanks for taking a look at my post. Unfortunately it was just a typo in my post. Now amended. kind regards